# Rank Over Partition in hive

Tags: hiveql

I have data in table A as below with 3 columns property id, end date and key, The key field has to be populated with a unique value for each of the unique combination of property id and end date as shown below

```
key property id end date
1   7050    12/31/9999
2   7530    12/31/9999
2   7530    12/31/9999
2   7530    12/31/9999
2   7530    12/31/9999
3   7541    12/31/9999
3   7541    12/31/9999
3   7541    12/31/9999
4   7567    12/31/9999
4   7567    12/31/9999
```

I  have tried doing

```
select rank() over (partition by property_id,effective_end_date) as key,
       property_id,
       end_date 
 from table A
```

but its assigning 1 as key to all records. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below command ,use order by:

```
select rank() over (ORDER by property_id,effective_end_date) as key,
   property_id,
   effective_end_date from table A
```

Answer (score 1):

It works just by adding the **Order by** as below:

```
select rank() over (partition by property_id order by effective_end_date) as key,
       property_id,
       end_date 
 from table A
```